# AIX Unix find command to get first element then move on to the next

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find, aix

My `list.txt` file has a few hundred entries pointing to filenames laying on the `/tmp` partition.  I'm collecting files that start with "a" such as `apples.txt`, `andromeda.txt`, etc to copy them into a directory.

However, I do not want to copy *all* the files but only the *first* file found. It doesn't have to be sorted; just the first one.

How do I do that? Any tips are welcome.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `/usr/bin/cat /tmp/list.txt`
  do
    find /tmp/$i -name a* -exec cp {} /tmp/found_first_file_start_with_a \;
  done
```

Comment: You lost me.  If `/tmp/list.txt` contains *file* names, why are you using `find` (which takes directories as positional parameters)?

Comment: Don't you just search through the file (`list.txt`) for the first line where the last component of the name starts with `a`?  Using `find` seems like it's wasteful unless some of the names may have been removed before you get to make the copy (and there are ways around that if it is part of your problem).  Maybe `sed -n '\%/a[^/]*$%{p;q;}' /tmp/list.txt`?

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't match with my interpretation of your question:
`for all subdirectories of /tmp given in /tmp/list.txt copy a file starting with the letter a to another directory`. Can you edit your question so others will understand what you wanted and why you use list.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget `find`, try this:

```
set -- /tmp/a*
test -z "$1" || cp "$1" /tmp/found_first_file_start_with_a
```

Comment: Some of the files may be in subdirectories under `/tmp`, and there might not be a file starting with `a` directly in `/tmp`, so your glob might not map to an existing file (and in Bash you'd need to set `shopt -s nullglob` to get nothing rather than the name `/tmp/a*` generated).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-quit` command to `find` to get it to stop after the first one:

```
find /tmp -name a* -exec cp {} /tmp/found_first_file_start_with_a \; -quit
```

however, this will only quit if the exec returns true.  If the cp command fails (for whatever reason), it will continue searching for more files.  So you can instead just print the first file and capture it for a separate `cp` command:

```
file=$(find /tmp -name a* -print -quit)
cp $file /tmp/found_first_file_start_with_a
```

Comment: The AIX 7.2 manual for [`find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm) doesn't seem to list `-quit` — though it is fairly close to a GNU `find` in its capabilities.